# Calling one image from (488, 648, 300) <class 'tuple'> in Python

Tags: python, matlab

I have a small doubt in calling an image from set of images in Python.

The idea is like how we load '.mat' file in matlab and calling one image through simple command line in matlab (below example):

```
load('psi0V.mat');

imagedat=psi;

imagedat=squeeze(imagedat);

I = imagedat(:, :, 1);

imagesc(I)
```

I am trying something similar in Python, but I am not able to call one image out of all images. I tried exploring all possibilities but not able to.

**Python code:**

```
import cv2 as cv

import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from scipy.io import loadmat

data = loadmat(r"F:\second_year\Code\Python_pixelinfo\psi0V.mat")

imagedata = data["psi"]

image = np.squeeze(imagedata)

image = np.shape(image)

I = image[:, :, 1]

print(image)

print(type(image))
```

**Error:**

```
============ RESTART: F:\second_year\Code\Python_pixelinfo\pixel.py ============
(488, 648, 300)
<class 'tuple'>

============ RESTART: F:\second_year\Code\Python_pixelinfo\pixel.py ============
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\second_year\Code\Python_pixelinfo\pixel.py", line 11, in <module>
    I = image[:, :, 1]
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

Kindly advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is due to this line.

```py
image = np.shape(image)
```

You are changing the value of `image` to a `tuple` of it's shape.

And comparing it with the **Matlab** code, I don't think it's even meant to be there.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for responding. Yes the code is working now. Many thanks again.